# Getting the breakpoint number from gdb

Tags: gdb

I am writing gdb command scripts to simplify the debugging. One of the problems I have
is that I am setting a breakpoint, and I want to disable it afterwards, and only enable it after another breakpoint is hit.

What I want to do is this

```
$my_break_number = break SomeFile.cpp:231
disable $my_break_number
```

but unfortunately gdb doesn't work this way. I have read the manual, but I cannot find any information on how to do this. Hopefully there is some information I have missed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

gdb will automatically set a convenience variable $bpnum with the last set breakpoint number.

You can possibly use that after setting a breakpoint to disable it (I haven't tested when a breakpoint is ambiguous and creates multiple breakpoints, I think it will work and disable all breakpoint locations created.)

see: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#Set-Breaks

if you need to use the breakpoint number from commands, that is probably not what you want, but it works for the question as specified.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I am looking for. I have read that page several times, but missed that $bpnum every single time. I will check it out and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Definitely works ... and useful, for example, for sourcing, from a file, commands such as 'condition', where the breakpoint number MUST be specified (as of emacs 27.1, gdb version 12.1), rather than just using the most recent breakpoint specification (the 'commands' command allows omission of breakpoint number, to imply most recent) ... per 'help condition' and 'help commands'. Thank you @matt.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you may want to use the [Python GDB scripting](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html), which gives you a lot better programmatic [access to breakpoints](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints-In-Python.html) than what is possible with "regular" command scripts.

Comment: I am going to have a look at the python scripting, it looks very exiting, but for now I am stuck with a gdb without python support.

Answer (score 0):

Also `info breakpoints` gives useful information such as:

number of breakpoint, how many time the breakpoint was hit, address in memory, what function is it in, file and line number of breakpoint